# How to notate a quick open and close hi-hat?

Tags: notation, drum-kits

How do I notate a hit on the hi-hat where the drummer opens the hi-hat when the stick hits the cymbal and immediately closes it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be understandable.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of hi-hat open and close notation:

[image]

The hats are notated by the **x** note heads above the top line of the staff. The **+** above a note indicates playing the closed hi-hat with a stick, and the **o** above a note head indicates playing an open hi-hat with a stick. If you want the drummer to play the hat with the stick again when closing the hat, you would notate it like this.

There are two ways to notate closing the hat without playing it again with the stick. One way is to notate it as above with a parentheses around the note head, like **(x)**, to indicate a ghost note. Another way would be to indicate playing the hat with the foot with a **+** above the foot note for clarity. Playing the hats with a foot is indicated with an **x** note head on the space below the bottom line of the staff as below:

[image]

Use normal note duration notation to indicate the timing of the opening and closing of the hats. If you find yourself feeling like 32nd or 64th notes are required for the very short duration you want, you might instead use a grace note for the open hat note.

Grace notes (often used to indicate a flam) look like this:

[image]